# import less file to another less file but not include it's content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I have two less files. one named main.less which imports bootstrap.less (which includes bootstrap variables.. etc.) and dash.less which has just styles for my dashboard. These two files should generate two css files. main.css and dash.css.

I'm including the main.css in to all my pages and the dash.css in to just the dashboard.

What i'm trying to do is: compile the main.less with included bootstrap variables in to main.css. Then compile the dash.less using the bootstrap.less variables in to dash.css. However this will result the contents of bootstrap.less to be included again in the dash.css which i don't want because i'm already including the main.css in my html.

Has anyone ever came across this ?

After trying several methods my decision was to use a grunt task to remove the duplicate css blocks.

Comment: why not to compile them to one file? many advantages to this (one of them - less round trips to the server to bring all the styles)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Found a way. I had to use import like this:

```
@import (reference) "bootstrap.less";

.myclass{color:@bootstrap-variable;}
.anotherclass{.classDefinedInBootstrapLessWhichUsesAVariableDefinedInVariablesLess}
```

Using "reference" will source the imported file but not include it.

Comment: This is simply amazing.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling all less files to one file will be good .But if you want to have variables of bootstrap.less in dash.less. Then there is one solution , if you see in bootstrap with less dump in bootstrap.less , component wise less files are included like -

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";

// Reset
@import "normalize.less";
@import "print.less";
```

etc.so if you want to use variables you can import '@import "variables.less"' in your 'dash.less' thats it :)

Comment: I already tried just import but it didn't do what i wanted. see my answer.

Comment: @astro Thanks I was unaware about this :)

Comment: Hey ,not getting exactly what you are trying to do but importing 'variables.less' also allows you to use variables in variables.less ..

Comment: but it won't import any classes defined in the bootstrap.less wouldn't it ? which i'm using in my less file. see my updated answer.

Comment: ohh .. okay .. But in question you asked about using variables and not about classes .. anyways thanks I was really unaware about reference  thing .. already voted up to your answer :)